# Import quoted CSV

Tags: sql-server, import, csv, bcp

I have a set of quoted CSV files, which I need to import into SQL Server. Files look like this:

```
"ColA","ColB","ColC"
"12345","John Smith","-75.33"
"12356","Jane Doe","43.12"
```

`BCP` and `BULK INSERT` commands do not work because SQL Server cannot handle quoted fields.

How can I import files such as above?

Comment: Not true. Both `BULK INSERT` and `BCP` support format files.

Comment: Yes, but suggested answer does not require format files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OPENROWSET** command and **Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)** driver come to the rescue:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET('MSDASQL',
'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)};
DefaultDir=D:\CSV file directory;
Format=CSVDelimited;
CharacterSet=ANSI;
',
'SELECT *
FROM [filename.csv]')
```